# First unbind old click function from plugin and then bind new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with slider function where there's a next button. When there's no other slide I want to unbind the previous click function and do something else with the click button.

Here is js

```
jQuery(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  var button = jQuery("._disabled").length;
  if (button) {
    jQuery( "._next" ).off("click");
    jQuery( "._disabled" ).on("click", handler);
  }
  var handler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.suggested').show();
    jQuery('.theiaPostSlider_slides').html('');
    jQuery('.theiaPostSlider_slides').append(jQuery('.suggested'));
    jQuery('._buttons').hide();    
  }
});
```

The HTML of the button is here:

```
<a rel="next" href="#" class="_button _next _disabled">
  <span class="_1">Next</span>
  <span class="_2"><span aria-hidden="true" class="tps-icon-chevron-circle-right"></span></span>
  <span class="_3"></span>
</a>
```

This is the website: [link](http://theemint.com/kate-upton-looking-quite-different-nowadays/5/)
When you click once to the Next button it works normally and then when it is on the last slide, it should unbind and then bind new function, but it only unbinds.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have some kate upton website as your link? Did you paste it by mistake. Can you please take a  look and make the appropriate edit.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to your question

Comment: @ShellZero i'm pretty sure that is his website just scrolldwon and hit the green next button you'll see what he is talking about

Comment: @finalfreq Aah, I see. :P

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `.on` and `.off` are the ways you can use for `.bind` and `.unbind`

If your jQuery version is less than 3, you can change it to this:

```
    jQuery( "._next" ).unbind("click");
    jQuery( "._disabled" ).bind("click", handler);
```

Otherwise, you can keep `.on` and `.off` by using the correct format. Something like this:

```
    jQuery( 'body' ).off("click", "._next");
    jQuery( 'body' ).on("click", "._disabled", handler);
```

More info:

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: yeah I forgot to switch it back, but it's not working either way